# How to set custom resolution for HDTV?

Tags: resolution, hdtv

Totally new to Ubuntu.  Trying to run it on a desktop to my HDTV.  However the edges of the screen are cropped off.  The res is too high.  It needs to be shrunk in a bit.

By using a bogus copy of Windows 7 I figured out that I need a res of 1847x1026.  How to I set Ubuntu to this res?  The PC is connected via HDMI.  I've tried editing xorg.conf in etc/X11.  I've tried creating a 10-monitor file.  The nvidia driver I have doesn't have a option to disable "Force FUll GPU Scaling".   I've google this issue to the point where I don't know what to try next.

Comment: Run this command once: `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1847x1026 --rate 60` then check what happens.. If that resolution would be in your xorg.conf file then it would change that this resolution.

Comment: I get the response we running it (with HDMI-0)..  xrandr: cannot find mode 1846x1026        but that setting is in the xorg.conf file.   file contents shown below

Comment: Section "Monitor"
 Identifier     "Monitor0"
 VendorName     "Unknown"
 ModelName      "SAMSUNG"
 HorizSync       29.0 - 68.0
 VertRefresh     30.0 - 60.0
 Option         "DPMS"
 # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
EndSection

Section "Screen"
 Identifier     "Screen0"
 Device         "Device0"
 Monitor        "Monitor0"
 DefaultDepth    24
 Option         "Stereo" "0"
 Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
 Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0; 1846x1026_60"
 SubSection "Display"
  Depth       24
 EndSubSection
EndSection

Answer (score 3):

In my situation, Ubuntu correctly identified my connection and TV - but I too could not see the Launch bar unless I changed the resolution or icon sizes. Turns out that changing the screen settings on the TV did the trick - Changed from a fixed 16:9 to "Just scan" and everything is perfect. Sanyo HD 46", HDMI